# Parallel javascript (River Trail) combine is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with [Intel's River Trail project](https://github.com/RiverTrail/RiverTrail/wiki). I installed the Firefox extension (FFv19.02). I also installed openCL for Windows. All the API methods seem to be working (map, reduce, scan, scatter, flatten, partition) , except the 'combine' method:

```
var par_A = new ParallelArray([3,3], function(i,j) {return j});
console.log( par_A.combine(function(i) {return this.get(i) + 1} ) );
```

I get:

```
TypeError: par_A.combine is not a function
```

Any idea what the problem might be ?

**UPDATE:**

So the above example makes no sense because you can't iterate over a 2D array with one combine. To simplify, let's take just a 1D example:

```
var par_A = new ParallelArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
console.log( par_A.combine(function(i) {return this.get(i) + 1} ) );
```

As stated bellow, there are two API methods, the one [proposed by Intel](https://github.com/rivertrail/rivertrail/wiki/ParallelArray), and the [ECMAscript draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3adata_parallelism).  The ECMAscript draft has no 'combine' method, but passes the index, as a second parameter to the 'map'. The equivalent of the above would be:

```
var par_A = new ParallelArray([1,2,3.4.5]);
console.log( par_A.map(function(v, i) {return this.get(i) + 1} ) );
```

Comment: Does "combineSeq" work?  There's a cryptic note in the API about it, but I'm not sure what it means as I'm almost completely unfamiliar with the project.

Comment: @Pointy Nope, tried that as well before posting the question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two APIs:

1. the River Trail API as described in the [GitHub prototype documentation](https://github.com/rivertrail/rivertrail/wiki/ParallelArray)
2. the Parallel JavaScript API described in the [ECMAScript proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3adata_parallelism)

The two differ slightly, one difference being that the ECMAScript proposal no longer has a combine method but uses a flavor of map that offers the same functionality. Another difference is that the GitHub prototype uses index vectors whereas the proposal version uses multiple scalar indices. Your example, for the prototype, would be written as

```
var par_A = new ParallelArray([3,3], function(iv) {return iv[1]});
par_A.combine(2, function(i) {return this.get(i) + 1} );
```

In the proposal version, you instead would need to write

```
var par_A = new ParallelArray([3,3], function(i,j) {return j});
par_A.map(2, function(e, i) { return this.get(i) + 1; });
```

Unfortunately, multi-dimensional map is not yet implemented in Firefox, yet. You can watch bug 862897 on Mozilla's bug tracker for progress on that front.

Although we believe that the API in the proposal is the overall nicer design, we cannot implement that API in the prototype for technical reasons. So, instead of evolving the prototype half way, we have decided to keep its API stable.

One important thing to note: the web console in Firefox seems to always use the builtin version of ParallelArray and not the one used by a particular website. As a result, if you want to play with the GitHub prototype, you best use the interactive shell from our GitHub website.

Hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: I see! but I edited your second example to make both examples "equivelant".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rolling my own combine method:

```
ParallelArray.prototype.combine_par = function ( fn) {
        var arr = this;
    var len = this.length;
    var indexes = [];

    //array to store the indexes [0,1,2...]
    for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
        indexes.push(i);
    }

    indexes = new ParallelArray(indexes);

    return indexes.map(function(val) {
            //use fn.call to keep 'this' in context
            return fn.call(arr,val);
    });


}
```

You can then call 'combine_par' like combine:

```
var par_A = new ParallelArray([3,3,3,3]);
//returns < 0,1,2,3 >
console.log( par_A.combine_par(function(i) {return i} ) );
```

PS: I tried the native [ParallelArray in firefox nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/), and [building the extension myself](https://github.com/RiverTrail/RiverTrail/tree/master/extension), but in both cases there was no 'combine' method

**UPDATE:**
For some reason, I can't use `this.get(index)` inside my combine_par callback function. So I use `this[i]` instead.